# Picking on a user (downvote abuse) question

Tags: support, down-votes, abuse

On SuperUser I have given just two questions and two answer.

A few minutes ago someone downvoted all of them.

Now, while it is technically possible that someone found all of them worth of a downvote, it smells much more like something personal (not that I have the slightest idea on who or why).

Is that behaviour acceptable?

Comment: don't see your username on SuperUser, so there's no way for me to see if your questions and answers are legitimate.  Looks like you're having the same luck here.

Comment: http://superuser.com/users/19032

Comment: @Robert Harvey, you can go to someones Meta profile and click Accounts. It'll show their associated accounts. Then you don't have to worry about searching on usernames.

Comment: @Robert: Even if the names weren't exactly the same, you could click on the accounts tab on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139415/looris

Comment: when I wrote this question the points were 0 / -1 / -1 / -1, when just a few minutes before were 1 / 0 / 0 / 0. Can't be a chance.

Comment: @Brandon: CURSE YOU FOR FGITW.  Now I go downvote all your answers.  I will have the last laugh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. If you think theres a problem you can either flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to take a look into it, or you can wait. There is a script that looks for [suspicious voting patterns](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and will correct the issue automatically.

Comment: do we know if four downvotes are enough to trigger a suspicious voting pattern though?

Comment: @Kip, I don't think the actual criteria is public. If it is, I'd be surprised. That'd be an open invitation for people to find ways to stay below the radar. I would think 4 votes within a few minutes on the same user might be enough to get the scripts attention, but I'm just guessing here.

Comment: thank you, I've flagged the post as you suggested, I'll let you know if there are news.

Comment: @kip - I'm pretty sure whatever number it is, it's >4 (based on experience sadly)

Comment: of course there have been no news about that. This system just suck.

Comment: I have been thinking of approaches to mitigate the trigger happy folks from impulsive/compulsive down voting. How about adding a simple delay or some fixed number of down votes before it gets really down voted?