# Downvote Abuse on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, down-votes, abuse, reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

I've recently had a series of 5-6 downvotes on SO, and so I've searched here and found [Picking on a user (downvote abuse) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30772/picking-on-a-user-downvote-abuse-question).

The answer there suggest to flag one post explaining the situation and wait for a mod to take a look.

When I tried that, my flag was declined:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

So what **can** I do if someone abuses downvotes against me?

Comment: If it's been less than 24 hrs, wait and see if the script that detects these things will correct it.  If not, and it's still going on, email the team directly.  Edit: As genesis points out below, there hasn't been any abnormal downvoting, just bounties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has already been said many times before.

Wait 36 hours for relevant script. If nothing happens, mail team@stackoverflow.com

I see no abuse on your account, so that's probably the reason of declining the flag.

Comment: Actually after I flagged it got removed, so I guess someone just tested or something. I just wanted to know what to do in case of. btw, `RikudoSennin == Truth` now :)